# Is it bad practice to re-assign a JavaScript function from within itself

Tags: javascript

### Scenario

I have an object in JavaScript. This object contains a function which will execute either `statementA` or `statementB` based on a `boolean` property. The `boolean` property should be considered read only, and for arguments sake let's say it's set within the constructor.

### Code

```
var MyClass = function(flag) {
    this.flag = flag; // this will never change after here
}

MyClass.prototype.go = function() {
    if (this.flag) {
        this.go = function() {
            // statement a (true)
        };
    } else {
        this.go = function() {
            // statement b (false)
        }
    }

    this.go();
}
```

[JS Bin demo](http://jsbin.com/vugigekuha/1/edit?js,console)

### Question

Is it bad practice to re-assign a method from within the scope of itself? I've tried to do some research into it, but so far I've been unsuccessful.

Comment: Why might it be a bad thing? Unusual to do within a constructor though. Another approach is to have a property that is used as a flag to choose which method to run.

Comment: @RobG Thanks Rob; that was going to be my other approach, simply having a condition within the function that executes the statement, but as I know the flag will never change, I was curious if this is a "recognisable" way of doing it.

Comment: It makes no sense to use a prototype for assigning the class function to this.

Comment: @NinaScholz I think you're missing the question at hand Nina; the code above is solely hypothetical.

Comment: i see, it is just a try to a make a partially applied function.

Answer (score 2):

It's the same, but more readable:

```
var MyClass = function (flag) {
    this.flag = flag; // this will never change after here
    this.go = flag ? function () {
        // statement a (true)
    } : function () {
        // statement b (false)
    };
}
```

Comment: This is better, OP method recreates the function with every call.

Comment: @Jonathan Sorry Jonathan but you're incorrect; this is demonstrated within my [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/vugigekuha/1/edit?js,console) example supplied in my original question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Nina; I appreciate the feedback on the readability side of things, albeit subjective. Ultimately I was intrigued to know if there were any limitations on re-assigning functions within their scope; this concern isn't apparent in your given answer, so could be considered a good alternative.

Comment: @Richard Ah, you're right. In that case I would argue that it is bad practice since there is no need whatsoever for the `go` function to override itself. It should be set properly in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I think, pass callback to prototype go, and other prototype will check and create callback from flag.

```
var MyClass = function(flag) {
    this.flag = flag; // this will never change after here
}

MyClass.prototype.go = function(cb) {
    // todo: your code
    cb();
}

MyClass.prototype.createCallbackForGo = function() {
    if(this.flag) {
        this.go(function() {
            alert('this is true');
        });        
    } else {
        this.go(function() {
            alert('this is false');
        });
    }
}

var classTrue = new MyClass(true);
classTrue.createCallbackForGo();

var classFalse = new MyClass(false);
classFalse.createCallbackForGo();
```